# MySQL find pairs in the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like this:

| id | id_dlry |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345.67 |
| 1 | 12345-68 |
| 2 | 12345 |
| 3 | 12345-67 |

I need to find pairs in column id_dlry where id's numbers are the same, but the sign changes from '.' to '-'

I added another temporary column to the table, where I can identify the sign like this:

```
update products  set check_sign =
                (case
                when id_dlry REGEXP '[0-9]{5}[.][A-Z0-9]+' THEN '1'
                when id_dlry REGEXP '[0-9]{5}[-][A-Z0-9]+' THEN '2'
                else '0'
                end);
```

so it looks like this:

| id | id_dlry | check_sign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345.67 | 1 |
| 1 | 12345-68 | 2 |
| 2 | 12345 | 0 |
| 3 | 12345-67 | 2 |

Now I would like to create another table only with pairs of records like "12345.67" and "12345-67", so it might look like this:

| id | id_dlry | check_sign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345.67 | 1 |
| 3 | 12345-67 | 2 |

I tried using inner join but I got stuck.

Comment: You 'forgot' to share the inner join where you got stuck with.

Comment: Maybe you should do: `SELECT  replace(replace(id_dlry,'.','#'),'-','#'), count(*), min(id_dlry), max(id_dlry) FROM products GROUP BY replace(replace(id_dlry,'.','#'),'-','#')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the new column. Use `count(*) over(partition by replace(id_dlry, '.', '-'))`:

```
select id, id_dlry
from
(select id, 
id_dlry,
count(*) over(partition by replace(id_dlry, '.', '-')) cnt
from products) t
where cnt > 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2294f90ac49403a2edf583dceeaca610)